# change image in every three days using php

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am creating a wordpress widget. This will allow user to upload the image url of eight different picture. Now I want to change the image everty three days and start from begining after eight one for infinite time.

I manage to get the start of the first image. let sat that is : 2014/07/28

I have applied this logic:

```
$date = $start_date;
                            $date = strtotime($date);
                            $date = strtotime("+3 day", $date);
                            $end_date = date('Y-m-d', $date);
                            $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
                            $end = new DateTime('');
                            $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
                            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
                            $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
                            if($start_date <= $end_date && $end_date > date('Y-m-d'))
                            {
                                $image_number = 1;
                            }else{
                            $i = 1;
                            $j = 1;
                            foreach($daterange as $date){
                                if($i%3 == 0){
                                    echo $image_number = $j;
                                    $j++;
                                    if($j > 8){
                                    $j = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                $i++;
                            }
                            }
```

?>
                            " alt="">

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code.

Thank you everybody in advance for your valuable time.

Comment: you should store the start date in some kind of database, as php cant save variables for more than one page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so it seems you have 8 images named 1.jpg to 8.jpg
Every three days you want to change the image to the next, and when you are at 8, you want to go to 1.

I don't know if you have some kind of start date on which the images were uploaded, and I don't know if it matters to you.

Let's start out with an example in which viewing the image is tied to the date (and resets on the first of january)

```
##maybe you would like to set the timezone
##date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$dayOfTheYear = date('z');  
$iterationCount = ceil($dayOfTheYear / 3);
$numberForIteration = $iterationCount % 8;

echo '<img alt="" src="'.$numberForIteration.'.jpg" />';
## prints for example: <img alt="" src="6.jpg" />
```

We can build on this and have an option of a different start date, meaning that not january 1st, but another date is the start date.

```
## PHP Version should be above June 2012

$startDate = new DateTime("2014-07-01");
$currentDate = new DateTime();

$daysSinceStart = $startDate->diff($currentDate)->days;
$iterationCount = ceil($daysSinceStart / 3);
$numberForIteration = $iterationCount % 8;

echo '<img alt="" src="'.$numberForIteration.'.jpg" />';
```

Hope it helps.

David